# How to handle an onClickListener for a Button within the Spinner onItemSelected(...) method?

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-button, onclicklistener

I have a `Spinner.onItemSelected()` method and I want to be able to have an event happen once a `Button` is clicked after selecting the `Spinner` item.

For example if you select Beginner for your Spinner and click Java for another spinner. Under that I have a button that says Start. How do I have a `Button.onClick` event correspond with the selected spinner options?

I did something like this but what I assigned as the `setOnClickListener()` value is not being read by the `View.OnClickListener`.

```
   public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
        long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    selected = (Integer) arg0.getItemAtPosition(0);
    position = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
    start = (Button)findViewById(R.id.start);
    start.setOnClickListener(phaseHandler);

    View.OnClickListener phaseHandler = new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    };


}
```

The `phaseHandler` I declared is not being read by `start.setOnClickListener(phaseHandler)` so this results in my `View.OnCLickListenr` invocation not working because `phaseHandler` is not being set to the `Button` start. In Eclipse my `phaseHandler` has the red underlining curly for an error where it says `start.setOnClickListener(phaseHandler);`

Any Ideas?

Comment: move start.setOnClickListener(phaseHandler); down to  View.OnClickListener phaseHandler = new View.OnClickListener() {...};

Comment: I did and still got an error. Do you mean to place withiin View.OnClickListenr(){ start.setOnClickListener(phaseHandler)}?

Comment: could you tell what the error you are getting?(in eclipse editor view left side bar, there is a red icon in the error line please hold the pointer it will display the error message)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

move start.setOnClickListener(phaseHandler); down
this may help you

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
        long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    selected = (Integer) arg0.getItemAtPosition(0);
    position = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
    start = (Button)findViewById(R.id.start);


    View.OnClickListener phaseHandler = new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    };

    start.setOnClickListener(phaseHandler);


}
```